# How to pass a value from modal window on one component to input on another component?

Tags: angular

I have component which only has modal and another component which has button **Edit position** and on click of that button it opens the Modal component. After selecting the position, the modal closes and the selected value has to be sent to input element on the component which opened it. Can someone help me on how to pass a selected value from modal to the input on another component ?

html:

```
<div class="form-group form-black">
  <label class="control-label">Position<label style="color:red;">*</label></label>
  <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="spr_position_id" #spr_position_id='ngModel' name="spr_position_id" [(ngModel)]="user.spr_position_id" required>  
     <span type="submit" class="input-group-addon btn btn-info" (click)="onOpenModule();">Edit position</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

modal.html:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h4 class="title">Select a position</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-content table-responsive ">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group form-black label-floating ">
          <input placeholder="Search…" type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" class="form-control" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th [class.active]="key === 'name'" (click)="setOrder('name')"><b>Position<span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span></b></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr  *ngFor="let spr_position of spr_positions | orderBy: key:reverse | filter:term">
              <td>{{spr_position.name}} </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <button type="submit" (click)="cancel();" class="btn btn-warning pull-left">Close</button>
          <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-info pull-right">Choose</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

modal.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogRef, ModalComponent } from 'angular2-modal';
import { BSModalContext } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import { SprPositionService} from '../../../services/spr-position/spr-position.service';
import { SprPosition } from '../../../models/spr-position.model';
import { Angular2TokenService } from "angular2-token";
import { OrderPipe } from 'ngx-order-pipe';

declare let moment: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spr-position-modal',
  templateUrl: './spr-position-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spr-position-modal.component.scss'],
  providers: [SprPositionService]
})
export class SprDolgModalComponent  implements ModalComponent<any> {

  spr_positions: Array<SprDolg>;
  key = 'name';
  reverse = false; 

  constructor(
    public dialog: DialogRef<any>,
    private orderPipe: OrderPipe, 
    public authTokenService: Angular2TokenService, 
    private servSprPosition: SprPositionService
  ) { 
    this.spr_positions = new Array<SprPosition>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadSprPositions();
  }

  private loadSprPositions() {
    this.servSprPosition.getSprPositions().subscribe((data: SprPosition[]) => {
      this.spr_positions = data;  
    });
  }

  setOrder(key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.reverse = !this.reverse;
  }

  cancel(): void {
    this.dialog.close(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, it sounds like you want to pass some data from child to parent component. Did you try to use `@Output()`?(EventEmitter)

Comment: No, I'll try to use @Output() now

Comment: I handle this by creating a popup service which allows me to call the modal component by route within that you can initialize you modal and assign your data to modal component

Answer (score 0):

Try using evnet emitter it should work.
refer this link
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data on dialog close

in modal.ts
`this.dialog.close(data)`;

in component.ts

```
onOpenModule(){
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open... 
 ...
 ...

 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
  // you can bind data to your model (this.user.spr_position_id = data )
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have UserListComponent which displays a list of users, when Edit button is clicked, it opens a Modal with UserFormComponent. When UserForm is closed, I can send some data back to UserListComponent by using `this.dialog.close(data);` (in UserFormComponent) and catch the data `dialog.result.then(data => console.log(data))`(in UserListComponent)

```
// UserListComponent
import { Modal, BSModalContext } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';
import { overlayConfigFactory } from 'ngx-modialog';

  constructor(
    public modal: Modal,
 ) { }

 editUser() {
   const dialog = this.modal.open(
      UserFormComponent, overlayConfigFactory({user: {userData}, isEdit: true}, BSModalContext));

   dialog.result.then( data => console.log(data))
 }
```

```
// UserFormComponent
import { DialogRef } from 'ngx-modialog';
import { Modal, BSModalContext } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';

  constructor(
    public dialog: DialogRef<BSModalContext>,
   ) {
    this.user = dialog.context['user'];
    this.isEdit = dialog.context['isEdit'] ? dialog.context['isEdit'] : false;
 }

  save(): void {
    this.dialog.close('Hello World');
  }
```